# Getting "Invalid URL Exception" on submit due to multiple form tags in Lotus Domino

Tags: javascript, html, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm getting the error, "Invalid URL Exception" on submit of a button. I am assuming that this issue is coming from three form tags I have in the web page.

In the body, the first form tag is for "post" of the fields and redirection. The second one, which is inside of the first form tag, is for the search bar as part of company header.

The third one is a form class for the input fields, which is also inside the first form tag.

I tried placing an end form tag in the first line of my code, it closes the form tag which now looks like this:

```
<form method = "post" action="/sample/sampleweb.nsf/myForm?OpenForm&amp;Seq=1" enctype="multipart/form-data" name=_myForm">

<input type="hidden" name="__Click" value="0">
</form>
```

Then the search form tag comes in after as also part of body. Upon clicking the submit button, I'm getting such error. When I tried searching by clicking the search, search functionality working as expected.

When I tried removing the form tag and end form tag for the search, and I click on Submit, it's working as expected.

I notice that domino is still creating end form tag at the last part of the page, right before the end of body tag. Could it be because of this?

To give you a better idea, here is the structure of it:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method = "post" action="/sample/sampleweb.nsf/myForm?OpenForm&amp;Seq=1" enctype="multipart/form-data" name=_myForm">
<input type="hidden" name="__Click" value="0">
</form> //This comes out when I add end form tag in the first line of code.

<form class="searchbox">
<input id="searchtxt" class="searchbox-submit">
<input type="submit" class="searchbox-submit">
</form>

<form class="form-horizontal">

//Rest of the code go here having the input fields.
<button type="submit" onclick="return validatefields(event)">Submit</button>
</form>


</form> //This part is the generated form tag.
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like your way of adding an extra form tag is correct: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21252029

Comment: Hi @PerHenrikLausten, I updated the description and code, forgot to mention that there is another form tag for the input fields. Not sure if it would be any help to finding out the solution. Could the issue be because of the nested form tag if I don't place the end form tag at the first line of code?

Comment: Why aren't you supplying method and action attributes in your form tags? Aren't they necessary since you have elements in the form with type="submit"?

Answer (score 0):

Domino creates the form tags for you because it assumes you are doing data entry if the form is in edit mode. To prevent this use the setting on the form properties second tab (propeller head) for "On Web Access" "HTML". With that you can do anything you want in HTML but as Richard suggested you need to define where to go when the form is submitted.

Once created this way you need to use the `?ReadFrom` url parameter rather than the `?OpenForm` parameter